# Потеря метаданных картинки, при переносе её на устройство, с помощью adb

Tags: android, adb, metadata

ДД, господа!
В общем проблема в описана заголовке. Нужно переносить картинку на устройство с помощью adb.
если использовать стандартный `adb push` то картинка перенесётся, но потеряет метаданные. Из-за чего не будет обнаружатся приложениями как картинка/фото.

Пробовал помещать картинку в архив и распаковывать её непосредственно на устройстве с помощью `adb shell unzip`, но проблема та же.

!!!При этом, если на устройстве, после переноса, вручную переименовать  картинку(или распаковать архив с картинкой), то метаданные появляются(правда уже новые. Не те которые были до переноса)

Comment: Обьясните о каких метаданных речь.